# Octave GUI freezes when trying to closed it on macOS

Tags: octave

After installing octave with `brew install octave`, I opened octave with GUI using the command `octave --force-gui`. But when I try to close the GUI it freezes.

I have tried to force quit it and use activity monitor to close it, but neither of them quitted it.

Operating system: macOS

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in Octave. Nothing you're doing wrong.

You can try installing the [Octave.app distribution](http://octave-app.org/) instead of Homebrew's Octave. It includes a patch to work around this bug.

Full disclosure: I am one of the maintainers of Octave.app.